# Struggling with sqlite3 gem on OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, sqlite

I'm new to Mac and Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to set up my environment.  I've been working through this tutorial and am stuck trying to get the sqlite3 gem installed on Mac OS X Lion.

- Xcode 4.2.1
- git version 1.7.5.4
- Ruby 1.9.3p0
- gem -v results in 1.8.11
- sqlite version 3.7.5

When I try to run `gem install sqlite3` or `gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/bin` I get the error text below, does anyone have any suggestions?

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/bin
checking for sqlite3.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
--with-sqlite3-dir
--with-sqlite3-include
--without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
--with-sqlite3-lib
--without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
--enable-local
--disable-local
/Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
from /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
from /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
from /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
from /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
from /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
from /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
from /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
from /Users/mikehking/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in `find_header'
from extconf.rb:34:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/mikehking/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/mikehking/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need the sqlite3 library files, which I imagine should be as simple as running

```
 sudo brew install libsqlite3-dev
```